# switch greek lowercase for times.sty to upright?

Tags: fonts, html

I need to "similarize" my latex output to web browser serif display.  I would like all math to be switched to upright and mimick html browsers, too. \usepackage{mathastext} \usepackage{times} \usepackage{amsmath} are good starts.

how do I get latex mathmode to default to upright lowercase greek letters to match the times font in its upright form now, rather than remain in italics. upgreek.sty would have been good, except that it requires me to change use in the document.

I want the latex \beta to look like β (&beta;) and not like *β* (<i>&beta;</i>), and preferably a little fattier than usual, too, because web browsers seem to be a little fatty...

Comment: Why do you want to mimic incorrect rendering? And it’s not web browsers that are the culprit, it’s incorrectly coded HTML documents. (And whether a character in a regular typeface looks fatty depends on the font, on the rendering engine, and the eye of the beholder.)

Comment: `times` is deprecated, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[upright]{txgreeks}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
This is text mode and now a math display:
\[ \alpha^n+\beta^m = \gamma^q \]
\end{document}
```

[image: txgreeks]

```
\[ \Gamma\cdot x+\Omega\cdot y=\Psi\cdot z \]
```

[image: more txgreeks]

Comment: except use the `newtx` package, which has better metrics for the `txfonts` fonts...

Comment: @wasteofspace yes, possibly, and I think this should be `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` on a recent installation. In this context, there is also `\MTsetmathskips` command from `mathastext 1.3a` and later which allows to have some extra space around letters in math mode.

Comment: is there a font that is a just little bit heavier here?  (this is because the Times font on OSX seems a little heavier than the txfonts, too.)

Comment: I don't know, not being knowledgeable in fonts. See perhaps the [Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not stuck with times, any font package that has a `french math` option (whatever be its exact name in the package) will do it. To my knowledge, `fourier`, `kpfonts`, `mathdesign` and `MinionPro` will do it. Perhaps also `MyriadPro`from the `FontPro` package

Answer (score 0):

How about using the flexible `lgrmath` package?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times}
% recent alternate to times
% \usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage[greek=up, Greek=it]{lgrmath}
% the default is greek=it and Greek=up.  Can specify greek font used.
% \usepackage[font=TheanoOldStyle-TLF]{lgrmath}
\begin{document}
A little text and $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\quad\Delta\Gamma\Lambda$.
\end{document}
```

[image: up greek]